# How do you not output to stderr from a Java app?

Tags: java, supervisord

How might I accidentally output to stderr from a Java app? I just read this:

http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-io/system-in-out-error.html

It would seem that this outputs to stdout:

```
System.out.println("File opened...");
```

and this to stderr:

```
System.err.println("File opening failed:");
```

I never knowingly output to System.err, but I wonder if some functions in Java do this automatically? Perhaps when an Exception is thrown?

I do this because I set up Supervisord to start and monitor my Java apps, and my apps emit some startup messages, and Supervisord records some messages to the stdout log, but others to the stderr log. I'd like to know how I could get control over this. Most of the stuff in stderr are the startup messages that I want the app to emit. They should be in the stdout log.

I originally posted this question to StackOverflow and I initially phrased it as a question about logs, so I was told it had to go to ServerFault. So I reposted it to ServerFault, but it got no response, mostly because I think it is really an application question. You can see the question on ServerFault here:

https://serverfault.com/questions/711199/how-would-i-tell-supervisord-that-these-messages-dont-belong-in-stderr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#setErr%28java.io.PrintStream%29

Just make some mock up class that does nothing but adheres to the PrintStream interface and you are good to go.

Comment: I am not sure I understand you. Are you saying the Standford library does this, or we need to wrap all calls to the Standford library?

Comment: I have no idea if it does, but if it does, you can intercept it this way. Try making your own PrintStream that does nothing and see if it gets called

Answer (score 0):

When an exception is thrown and not catched a thread-level [uncaught exception handler](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/index.html?java/lang/Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler.html) deals with it. If you have specified none then the default one is used. The JLS does not specify the default handler. But oracle's default handler prints to stderr. So that is a way to get stderr output without using `System.err`

Comment: But these messages are not Exceptions.

Comment: That is an example of getting output to stderr without using System.err . There are hundreds of libraries which output to stderr you may not be aware. There is no way around it than reading its documentation. If you want all output to go to stdout use Enerccio's answer to redirect stderr to stdout globally.